# My div is breaking out of its container div

Tags: css, html

I have a containing div that is NOT restricting the width of its child divs. The divs are stretching all the way to the full width of the screen, when i have a set width on both the container and the child.  Why is this happening. I do NOT have any positioning or floating going on.

Please view my HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs_commentArea">
    <li class=""><a href="#" class="">Starstream</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#" class="">Comments</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="paneWrap">
<div class="panes_comments">
    <div class="comments">member pane 1</div>
    <div class="comments">member pane 2</div>
    <div class="comments">member pane 3</div>
</div>
```

My CSS, the relevant parts of it at least:

```
#MembersColumnContainer {
    width: 590px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 0px;
    clear: none;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

ul.tabs_commentArea { 
    list-style:none; 
    margin-top: 2px !important; 
    padding:0;  
    border-bottom:0px solid #666;   
    height:30px;
}

ul.tabs_commentArea li {
    text-indent:0;
    margin:  !important;
    list-style-image:none !important;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    float: right;
}

#paneWrap {
    border: solid 3px #000000;

}

.panes_comments div {
    display: ;
    padding: px px;
    /*border:medium solid #000000;*/
    height:150px;
    width: 588px;
    background-color: #FFFF99;
}
```

Comment: Could you share some code please?

Comment: You will need to post your css and html for anyone to be able to answer that.

Comment: Please see my revised question

Comment: Which parts are breaking out of what? Can you be more specific?

Comment: #PaneWrap is the element that is stretching all the way across the screen, the border. I want it to just wrap around .panes_comments and have the same width as it. Ive tried to give #paneWrap a width, however that did not fix the problem, so i removed it.

Comment: For one who has no "floating going on", you have a lot of floating going on.

Answer (score 3):

You could set `max-width` on either, or both, of the `div` elements to prevent their expansion:

```
#containerDiv {
    min-width: 400px; /* prevents the div being squashed by an 'extreme' page-resize */
    width: 50%; /* defines the normal width of the div */
    max-width: 700px; /* prevents the div expanding beyond 700px */
}
```

It might also be that you're allowing the `div`'s overflowed contents to be `visible`, as opposed to `hidden` (or `auto`). But without specific examples of your mark-up and css it's very difficult to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Generally giving elements layout is pretty straight forward (always assuming you have a good understanding of floating, positioning and the box model), and in most cases you wouldn't have to use max- min-width to control elements on the page.

My two cents: If I was you, I'd start stripping out code (starting with the !important rule), and see when the problem is solved. De-constructing the code like that is a good way to find bugs.

Sorry I couldn't help, but I'm reluctant to give advice since the code you provided shows a lot of other stuff going on elsewhere that might be contributing to your problem (like having to use !important).

:D

Comment: removing important doesnt do anything at all it seems.

Comment: No, removing important might not change the code majorly, but it's generally accepted that using the rule is not a good idea. If you have to force something, it ain't good. :P Like I said, keep stripping it back, start out with the base elements and work up from there. If nothing else it'll be a great learning curve. :D

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  The file that was calling in the css was conflicting with another external css file that had the same element with the same name in it. Thank you all for your help though.